# swapping keyboard using alt+shift

Tags: 14.04, command-line, swap

I need to know how to swap between languages in Ubuntu 14.04.3 using  command line .

Comment: Are you on a virtual terminal or on an emulated terminal inside an X session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

Here "o" (zero) is the first layout, for other layout you have to change numbers in increasing order - 1,2,etc. So for your second layout you should run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```